# Node/Gulp with TFS builds

Tags: node.js, tfs, gulp, build-server

With the web app. I'm working on, we use Gulp to compile some stylesheets and scripts. These compiled files are used by the web app.

When we're developing locally, we don't have Gulp do the full compilation process because it takes about 50 seconds.

When we check-in to TFS, we want the build to do the full compilation as part of a gated check-in.

Our problem is that dev-ops will not allow us to install Node on the build machines.

How can we have TFS run gulp task on check-ins without installing Node?

Comment: It's ridiculous that they "won't let" you install a critical dev tool on a machine that's intended to be an automation time-saver. What's their rationale? A build server should be as close to identical to a developer workstation as possible. If developers are using node-based tools, node should be on the build server. End of story.

Comment: I second Daniel. You should escalate this as a blocking issue untill you get to someone who can deal with it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say this is similar to the problem folks have when they can't `sudo`. [Isaac Schlueter](https://github.com/isaacs) was writing [this great Gist](https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814) where at least one of the options to install node and hence npm should be working for you. I was testing it with the first one.

**TL;DR**

> Build `node.js` and hence `npm` locally, on the build server or into your repo and run their local bin-files manually. Flaw: In the end you'd consider it to be an installation anyway plus the build task might run very long.

**Alternative**

> Let them provide you a node-based open-source build server like [Strider](https://github.com/Strider-CD/strider) in your network. For convenience: there is also a pre-configured [docker container](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/niallo/strider/).

Anyhow the solution requires you to have sufficient access rights to the build machine, since a gulp installation will try to build native code. Also python must be install since node.gyp relies on it.

Your starting point is your repo where you should install node in any dependency folder. This could all happen fully or partly as shell script on the build machine.

```
mkdir deps && cd $_
curl http://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz | tar xz --strip-   components=1
cd node-v0.12.0
./configure
make install
curl https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

This should render you with something like the below.

```
.
├── node_modules
├── deps
|   └── node-v0.12.0
├── client
|   ├── scss
|   |   └── somestyle.scss
|   ├── css
|   |   └── somestyle.css
|   ├── footer.html
|   └── header.html
├── Gulpfile.js
├── app.js
├── package.json
```

Now run from project root.

```
# local npm install ...
./deps/node-v0.12.0/deps/npm/bin/npm-cli.js install gulp
# and to run your Gulpfile default task
./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js
```

There are many solutions path which might lead to the same result but revolve around the some idea, as illustrated above.